# Can the first term of geometric sequence be equal to zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can the first term of geometric series be equal to zero?

For example $a_1 = 0, q = 5$ then $a_n = \text{{0, 0, 0, 0, ...} ?}$

Comment: You're pretty much answering your own question with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, but then **all** the terms will be 0, independent of the value of $q$.

Quite a 'boring' sequence, but it still fits the definition of a *geometric sequence*.

Note: you may want to distinguish between [*series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and [*sequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

Comment: Oh, I meant "sequence", thanks

Comment: From your example, I assumed you did :-). You're welcome.